# npm looking for package.json in user directory

Tags: javascript, npm

I've just finished up writing a test suite, and after adding the test file to the npm scripts object in the local package.json, I appear to have warnings that the package.json cannot be found in the user directory.

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\chris\package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\chris\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\chris\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-04T16_59_06_479Z-debug.log
```

Why is it going to the user directory instead of the current directory, which is C:\Users\chris\Google Drive\code projects\firebase-form\firebase-form? Is it a problem with the script test command, which is "test": "mocha tests/firebase-listeners-tests.js"?

i am running `npm test` from the local directory but nothing seems to be working. here is how i linked my test script in the package.json: `"test": "tests/resources tests.js"`

Also, for additional information here is my projects file structure:

```
firebase-form/
├── tests/
│   ├── firebase-listeners-tests.js
│   ├── resources tests.js
│   └── test_dependancy-fake_data_for_firebase.js
└── package.json
```

As you can see I do not have an entry point .js file, but that's because I haven't wrapped up the testing yet.

Also here is the repo link: https://github.com/LeviathanTheGreat/firebase-form

Comment: Are your project files directly in the `chris` folder

Comment: I don't think is a good idea to name the file with a space. I use npm for nodejs and my start script looks like this: `"start": "node index.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fixed**

I had forgotten to put "node" in front of the file in the test command. as well I had changed the filename like @awesomeguy had suggested. But I had forgotten to change it in the package.json